# Conceptual Question about finding relation between one categorical variable and one numeric variable

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, clustering

The data looks like this

```
Vehicle                   MilesPerGallon      DriverID    Date
Mazda 6 2016                8.6               10014       11/14/2017
Toyota Camry 2014           12.4              10051       11/4/2017
Nissan Altima 2012          7.1               10014       11/15/2017
Nissan Altima 2012          9.3               10065       11/15/2017
Mazda 6 2016                8.1               10058       11/15/2017
```

My objective is to find which vehicles give me good MilesPerGallon or in other words, what is the relation between Vehicle and MilesPerGallon

The project is about creating a scoring algorithm for drivers based on their performance(with the goal on how to improve MPG). The first part is to calculate score based on driver behavior. I have done that.

Now I should not penalize the drivers because they are driving old vehicle or vehicle that are not efficient. To take the vehicle out the equation, I want to normalize the score based on what vehicle they are driving.

What I did for that was, ran correlation between Vehicle and fuel economy and if they value is -ve, I added that value to score. if the correlation is +ve, I subtracted that value from the final score. I know this is not the correct method.

How to find the relation and normalization value?

Comment: The whole objective is to improve the MPG

Answer (score 2):

You can just calculate average miles per gallon for each given vehicle, e.g.

E(Miles per gallon | vehicle = Mazda 6 2016) =(8.6+8.1)/2